# Scan IP range for SSL/TLS versions and vulnerabilities with legible/greppable output

Tags: ssl, grep, nmap, port-scanning

I'm looking to find computers on the network that are using older versions of tls/ssl.

So far I've been using nmap's ssl-enum-ciphers and ssl-poodle scripts but the output isn't helpful as it shows every cipher available, eg :

```
Nmap scan report for x.x.x.x
Host is up (0.017s latency).

PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   SSLv3:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|     compressors:
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: server
|     warnings:
|       CBC-mode cipher in SSLv3 (CVE-2014-3566)
|   TLSv1.0:
|     ciphers:
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 2048) - A
```

I have seen nmap has the greppable output option "-oG" but I'm not sure it works in conjunction with scripts, or I'm not using it correctly.

I've been using a variation of the below command

```
nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 {ip address/netmask}
```

Ideally I'd like the output to look like

IP Address/Hostname
SSLv3
TLS1.0
TLS1.2

But even getting it into .csv format would be helpful.
Is there a better way to do this? Maybe I'm lacking some grep knowledge here.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this just me, or does "nmap -sV --script ssl--enum-ciphers -p 443 {ip address/netmask}" result in "NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
/usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:823: 'ssl--enum-ciphers' did not match a category, filename, or directory"

Comment: Yep, my bad. Double dash between ssl and enum when it should only have been a single dash. Edited now. Thanks!

Comment: LOL, thought I had to download it, did so, and ended up with a version incompatible with my nmap.  Reinstalled nmap.

Comment: You can try to run all the ssl tests nmap has `nmap --script ssl* -p 443`, and then you see which others scripts are valuable for you

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind awk, I've concocted a checkciphers.sh script, as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 | awk '
  /^Nmap scan report for /{
    currhost = $5 " " $6
  }
  /^443\/tcp /{
    if ($2 != "open") {
      currhost = ""
    }
  }
  /^\|   (TLS|SSL)/{
    currciph = $2
  }
  /^\|     ciphers:/{
    count = 1
    next
  }
  /^\|     [^ ]/{
    count = 0
  }
  /^\|       [^ ]/{
    if ("$currhost" && count > 0) {
      host[currhost] = 1
      ciph[currhost][currciph] += 1
    }
  }
  END {
    for (H in host) {
      CC=""
      for (C in ciph[H]) {
        CC=CC " " C ciph[H][C]
      }
      print H,CC
    }
  }
'
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot! I'm not overly familiar with awk but I can definitely figure it out, cheers :)

Comment: Hi, I'm seeing the following errors with this :

```
 source checkciphers.sh
awk: line 23: syntax error at or near [
awk: line 29: syntax error at or near [
awk: line 34: syntax error at or near }
```
I've added a test ip with a /32 netmask to test it.

Comment: Can you show the output of "nmap -sV --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443" that causes this?   And what do you mean with "I've added a test ip with a /32 netmask to test it" ?